# Could a nop instruction ever take more than 5 cycles in the pipeline?

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture, pipelining

A nop instruction is defined as:

```
sll  $0,$0,0
```

Since $0 is a read-only register, could a nop ever be stalled in the 5-stage MIPS pipeline? That is, could it ever take more than 5 cycles to execute?

Comment: You didn't mention the processor. That makes the question meaningless.

Comment: Just using the 5-stage MIPS pipeline.

Comment: Please edit the question.

Comment: @ineedahero There is no such thing as a “5 stage MIPS pipeline.” Every processor has a slightly different pipeline, so specify one.

Comment: The [classic-RISC pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) is a well-known thing.  Clearly that's what the OP really means.

Answer (score 0):

I will not be stalled.

Update:
Now come to think of it, may be there is a way to stall it if you really want to.
If the instruction misses in the cache, the instruction fetch stage can be stalled.